# Client to Web socket server to socket client implementation

Tags: sockets, go, websocket

I am trying to build a application that be behave as server and client that will be written in go.
as a big picture, 
web/php websocket client(java script to websocket access) <-> go server(websocket server & socket client) <-> tcp socket server

For starting, I have implemented go to be a socket client, built protocol layer to communicate properly with my socket server and I have used some web socket library to be a websocket server.

My question is how can I pair each connection in secure way and manage connection without hassle.

I was thinking something like pair data structure to tack.

in go-lang syntax

```
var track_connection map[wss_connection]socket_connection
// create map data with web socket to be a key and track socket connection
```

this way i can look up the connection by web socket connection.

I am not sure this is clear enough to be a question
please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your go app is translating between websockets and a raw tcp protocol? Does it need to read the content at all or just relay raw bytes?

Comment: I do not translate the bit and bytes I will write translate functions to call socket command and whatever information I retrieve from the socket server will translated and relay back to websocket.

Comment: For managing connections, am I on the right track?